# Converting javascript Winston factory class to ES6

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, winston

I'm currently working on converting a Winston Factory in Javascript to a Typescript file written in ES6. The example below gives me a Winston logger which I can use in other classes by importing it and calling *log.info();* The lab parameter is a label that you can give to the logger per file.

```js
module.exports = lab => 
 winston.createLogger({
  level: "verbose",
  transports: [new transports.Console({
    format: combine(colorize(), label({
      label: lab
    }), timestamp(), ms(), logFormat),
  }), ],
});
```

I'd like to use this approach in my Typescript application but I'm struggeling with getting it to work with the ES6 import statements. This is what i've come up with so far, this approach allows me to import the logger into another file, but I can't reach the logger functions.

```js
export = lab =>
  winston.createLogger({
    level: "verbose",
    transports: [
      new transports.Console({
        format: combine(
          colorize(),
          label({ label: lab }),
          timestamp(),
          ms()
        ),
      }),
    ],
  });
```

Any input, tips or even a name of the code structure in the old file so that I can Google more about it would be appreciated.

**Edit**

My problem:
I use import log from "fileLocation" to import the file.
When I call log, I would expect to get the winston logger functions, but I get the following functions.

[image]

Comment: What is the problem you are running into exactly? You cannot import this Typescript file in another file? Or your imports in this Typescript file don't work?

Comment: My problem is that the object that I import isn't the Winston object. In the old javascript project, I get the Winston function on the imported object, but in my new project that doesn't work. I've added a screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are exporting a function so, your imported `log` is the function `(lab) => ...`

If you do:

`const myLog = log();`

In `myLog` you will find the object created by `winston`

Comment: I see, this did the trick. Would it be possible to achieve this without the use of the myLog variable? Something that I could change about the export so that it would be the winston object straight from the import maybe?

Comment: If you want to pass the param lab, AFAIK no.